# How do you construct the complete Rotation matrix for use in a Camera matrix for a software renderer with a rotatable camera.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, projective-geometry, projection

(It might not seem like it at first, but I promise this is a mathematics question, not programming.)
Hi, I'm writing a 3D software renderer in C++. I'm projecting objects from the 3D world onto a 2D plane using a [camera matrix](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E16385/s17/Slides/11.1_Camera_matrix.pdf).

I've implemented a Camera object that has a position vector in space and 3 relative direction vectors.

For instance the world centre is (0,0,0) and it's x,y,z vectors are (1,0,0), (0,1,0), and (0,0,1).
The camera position and relative directions can be (and is most likely) different to these.

So now we get to the conundrum I'm having. I know that the Camera matrix can be calculated as P = KR[ I|C]. What I'm not sure about is what is meant by R?

I know you get rotation matrices for rotating around an axis, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), but what if the vector has been rotated around multiple axes? Is there a general R?

Currently I've been working under the asssumption that you can construct the "R" you need by simply premultiplying some of the standard ones together, kindof like you're rotating about one axis, then the next, and so on... Is this correct?

Comment: All rotations in 3 dimensions rotate about some axis. But "axis" here means "some line through the center", not "coordinate axis". And depending on what information you have defining the rotation, it may be quite hard to find that axis.  In this case, if you know what the three unit axis vectors of the camera coordinate system are in world coordinates, then $R$ is just those three column vectors put together in a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\hat x&\hat y&\hat z\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: For ways of defining rotation matrices by rotations about coordinate axes, look at [Euler Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). Particularly, you should look at Tait-Bryan angles (which are generally the easiest to use). Note the "Rotation matrices" part of the article.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSinclair , your first comment really helped (and the second one is really interesting). So the R is really just a change of basis transformation matrix? In that case, shouldn't it be the inverse of [̂ ̂ ̂ ]?

Comment: Any invertible matrix is a change of basis transformation matrix. A rotation is a change of *RH-oriented orthonormal basis* transformation matrix. Any such matrix also has the beautiful property that the transpose is the inverse. As for which transformation you need, that depends on whether you are transforming from world coordinates to camera coordinates or vice versa. I admit that in skimming through that very, very long-winded reference, to find where the formula you were asking about actually occurred, I did not work that out.